# Get image bands corres[ponding to indices and create an rgb image?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

i have a program and i want to do band selection. I am able to generate the indices that i have selected for further processing. But i am not able to create an RGB image out of those and i also want to create a .mat file of the bands i have selected? my insdices are in sel_bands_list?

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
from tqdm_progress import TqdmUpTo
import scipy.io as scio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import h5py
import mat73
def main():
remove_bands = []
mat_dict = mat73.loadmat('0042.mat')
   
for key in mat_dict:
    if type(mat_dict[key]) is np.ndarray:
        image_data = mat_dict[key]  # type: np.ndarray

cols = image_data.shape[1]
rows = image_data.shape[0]
bands = image_data.shape[2]

image_data = image_data.reshape(cols * rows, bands)
sel_bands_list = []
sel_bands_list = mev_sfs(image_data, 3, remove_bands)
```

Comment: Band selection ? Is that like choosing your favorite musical group ?

Comment: Please try harder to present your question properly. Python requires correct indentation and `import` statements. You will be far more likely to get an answer if you pose your question with correct formatting and all ancillary information.

Comment: My question is, i want to convert that '0042.mat' file into another mat file. but using only some selected bands. The band indices that i need are given in sel_bands_list.